# Where can I find the cause of this error message? (rails 3.2.8 nested form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

My New Contract Form use to work ... it still needs some refinement ... but the current version use to work, but now I am getting this message:

```
 3 errors prohibited this codeline from being saved:

 There were problems with the following fields:

   Contract can't be blank
   Client can't be blank
   Code can't be blank
```

I do not have any fields named Contract, Client, or Code ... those are my models.

Here is the params which I raised in the codelines_controller:

```
{"contract_attributes"=>{"authnum"=>"900700", "st_date"=>"2012-09-03",
 "end_date"=>"2012-12-31"}, "client_attributes"=>{"f_name"=>"Esme", "mi"=>"J",
 "l_name"=>"Inneed", "birth_date"=>"1986-03-18", "address1"=>"62 Southy View",
 "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Fromm", "zip_code"=>"55803", "state"=>"WI",
 "medicare_num"=>"3008769788", "medicaid_num"=>"765894567", "member_num"=>"6709875-3",
 "soc_sec_care_mgr"=>"Caring Manager", "sscm_ph"=>"1-444-444-4444",
 "nurse_care_mgr"=>"Caring Nurse", "ncm_ph"=>"1-555-555-5555", "emer_contact"=>"Always
  Here", "ec_ph"=>"1-666-666-6666", "pri_care_phy"=>"The One", 
 "pcp_ph"=>"1-777-777-7777"}, "code_attributes"=>{"code_name"=>"S-5463",
 "status"=>"Active", "description"=>"Transition from schl to work"},
 "units_alloc"=>"100.00"}
```

as you can see all of the fields that need data have data and are not 'blank'

I did contract out to see if I could get a professional to help me design a button to add extra attributes to the form, but I had to cancel the contract because they were not communicating. So part of this process required that I make them collaborators to github and heroku. Maybe they had to change something to work on the project?

Can someone give me some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `CodeLine`(?) object probably has not been assigned a `Contract` , `Client` or `Code` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in app/models/theModelThatIsUsed.rb and if you find something like:

```
validates :contract, :presence => true
validates :client, :presence => true
validates :code, :presence => true
```

delete that lines

Comment: I deleted 'code' validates(:contract_id etc) 'code' and it works ... wow thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry... what are you saying?

Comment: I deleted a validates(:contract_id, :client_id, :code_id) form my codeline.rb model and now my form works ... thanks